# In Entity Framework, is it possible to "Add Foreign Key Properties to [Table Name] Entitiy" after generating the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

We have a large entity model that has been built up over x years, and I was wondering if the following was possible:
We have a lot of old entities where we don't directly expose the foreign keys to other tables, but they have an association in entity framework. i.e. Table 1, has a 1-many relationship to Table 2, Table 2 has a Table1_ID field on the database table, but I can't access that from within my C#/Entity Framework code. Is there a clean way to show this/add this without deleting the association and readding it?
This is in Model First Entity Framework

Comment: *but I can't access that from within my C#/Entity Framework code* Why not? If this is database-first (I don't think it's model first, since you generate the EDMX?), the column should be part of the EDMX, shouldn't it?

Comment: @GertArnold Exposing the generated column is optional when adding the association, this is older code written by someone else and didn't include the property, so its on the generated table, but I cant do Table2.Table1_ID, I can only do Table2.Table1 which means I need to include that table to query it, when I only need the ID field.

Comment: My underlying question was, can't you change the code? It's much easier to expose primitive FK properties in the class model (foreign key associations vs independent associations).

Answer (score 1):

You can use data annotation and add a property on your `Table2` model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
...
[Column("Table1_ID")]
public int Table1Id { get; set; }
```

If you are using the fluent api, you can configure it like that:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>() 
        .Property(t => t.Table1Id) 
        .HasColumnName("Table1_ID");
}
```

Then create a new migration and remove everything inside the `Up` and `Down` functions.

```
public partial class Add_Table1_Reference_To_Table2_Model : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention it was model first :( Thank you though

Comment: @Thomas - Model First uses EDMX files and doesn't use migrations.

Comment: @ScottBecker, ohh ok you are using an old version of EF. I haen't noticed and read properly your question. sorry for that.

Comment: @Thomas All Good, sorry haha I forget that there are MUCH newer versions than ours.